# Ejecutable se cae al abrirlo Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Muy buenas, tengo un problema con una aplicación que cree con tkinter, al momento de abrir el exe me muestra la consola de comandos y luego se cae, intente creando un proyecto nuevo, una simple ventana con botones y labels y obtengo el mismo resultado.

use este comando para convertirlo en exe

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

estos son los errores que muestra al abrirlo con la consola de comandos

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py", line 49, in 
File "c:\users\salva\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
File "win32com_*init*_.py", line 5, in 
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida.
[10936] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_win32comgenpy

C:\Users\salva\OneDrive\Datos adjuntos\Spython\Tkinter-3\dist\rmain>r

Comment: Logre solucionar en parte mi problema, lo que hice fue mudarme de visual studio code a pycharm, me cree un entorno virtual, reconstrui de nuevo mi aplicacion, de momento llevo 300 lineas de 1000, convertí el script en exe, y me funciono en parte, el problema es que las imagenes no aparacen en la aplicacion, asi que tuve que copiarlas y pegarlas en la carpeta dist que te entrega pyinstaller.

Comment: Para agregar una imagen sin tener que copiarla manualmente a *dist* utiliza `--add-data`, por ejemplo: `pyinstaller --add-data "image.png;." main.py`

Comment: Gracias no me sabia esa.